# Не работает Bluetooth в Ubuntu 18.4

Tags: linux, ubuntu, драйвер, bluetooth

Проблема с подключение устройств bluetooth (наушники) он их видит но не подключается к ним. Система Ubuntu 18.4

Вот вывод команды `sudo dmesg | grep -i bluetooth`

```
[    4.801372] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    4.801385] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    4.801387] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    4.801389] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    4.801393] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    5.006826] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 63
[    5.007827] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: features 0x07
[    5.023819] Bluetooth: hci0: kacub18pc
[    5.027820] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM20702A1 (001.002.014) build 0000
[    5.028111] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM20702A1-13d3-3411.hcd failed with error -2
[    5.028113] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM20702A1-13d3-3411.hcd not found
[    6.141323] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    6.141324] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    6.141327] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   24.919838] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   24.919844] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   24.919848] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[   45.283908] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
[   67.299970] Bluetooth: hci0: last event is not cmd complete (0x0f)
```

Comment: Гляньте [тут решение.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/787023/bluetooth-not-working-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts) Хорошего дня!

Comment: В этом конфиге `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf` уже стоит `AutoEnable=true` не помогает

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/592145/110559